# Does $ \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} (\frac{2}{(-1)^n - 3})^n$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to show that $ \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} (\frac{2}{(-1)^n - 3})^n$ either converges or diverges. WolframAlpha is telling me it converges, but I'm not sure how to show this. I tried using the ratio test and it was inconclusive, so now I'm a little stumped on this. My definition of the root test is that if $\lim \sup \frac{c{n+1}}{c_n} < 1$, then $\Sigma c_n$ converges absolutely. The test is inconclusive if $\lim \sup \frac{c{n+1}}{c_n}  \leq \lim \inf \frac{c{n+1}}{c_n} $

Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Are you talking of root or ratio test?

Comment: Sorry! Bad typo on my end. I was talking of ratio test. I did try the root test but it ended up being inconclusive too.

Comment: Can you rewrite the statement of the terms of the series a little more carefully. It is a little confusing to me as it stands. Also preferably put the entirety of the question into the body of the question. No important information should only be found in the title as a general rule of thumb.

Comment: @Nikitau whether the power $n  $ is for the whole fraction or only for 2?

Comment: @jgon Thanks for that! Rewrote the question and added it into the body. Should've been more careful with that.

Comment: @vidyarthi Edited the post for further clarity. It is for the entire fraction of $\frac{2}{-1^n -3}$

Answer (score 2):

We have that the $2n$'th term of the sum is $\dfrac{1}{2n}$ and the $2n+1$'th term of the sum is $-\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)2^{2n+1}}$.

Then the sum of the positive terms is  $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{2n}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}=+\infty$.

Moreover, since
$$
\left|-\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)2^{2n+1}}\right|=\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)2^{2n+1}} \leq \dfrac{1}{2^{2n+1}}
$$  the sum of the negative terms converges. Therefore, the whole sum diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but for some reason WolframAlpha thinks that sequence converges? Or is this an error on their end? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=does+(1%2Fn)*(2%2F(-1%5En+-3))%5En+converge

Comment: I guess it's because you forgot to put the parenthesis around the $-1$.

Comment: great answer, avoiding the leibniz alternating test!

Comment: @Nikitau Be careful, on that link you sent me Wolfram did not summed the series.

Comment: Ah I see. This might be another dumb question, but which test shows that the negative terms converges? Is it by limit comparison test?

Comment: Well, the sum over their modulus certainly converges, because it is dominated by the geometric progression $\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{2^3}, \dfrac{1}{2^5},...,\dfrac{1}{2^{2n+1}},...$ (here we are using the comparison test and the fact that every series of a geometric progression with ratio strictly less than 1 converges). It means that the sum of the negative terms is absolutely convergent, so it must be convergent.

Comment: by comparison test I mean the direct comparison test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test

Answer (score 0):

There's clearly behaviour that differs between the even and odd terms that causes the use of the ratio test to be tricky.

What I'd do is combine adjacent terms, using $n=2j+1$ for odd terms and $n=2j+2$ for even. Then we can write:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{2}{(-1)^n-3}\right)^n =
\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2j+1} \left(\frac{2}{(-1)^{2j+1}-3}\right)^{2j+1} + 
\frac{1}{2j+2} \left(\frac{2}{(-1)^{2j+2}-3}\right)^{2j+2}
$$

Some simplifying gives this as

$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{-1}{2j+1}\frac{1}{2^{2j+1}} + \frac{1}{2j+2}
$$

Which we can now show diverges using a limit comparison test with $\sum 1/j$.